# Azure APIM import all operations from Backend service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am working on a Azure APIM and i have my webapi hosted as Azure app service. My webapi has more than 60 controllers and 200 endpoints. I have added the App service to APIM. I need to add backend service endpoints as operations. As far as i tried i was able to add the operations manually one by one. but is there a way to import all operations directly from Backend API in a single shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide APIM with a specification for your backend API. OpenAPI format is very commonly used, it can be autogenerated by using tools like Swashbuckle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle